# builtins.ImportError: cannot import name 'choices'

Tags: python, random

I am trying to import choices from the random library in python but I get an error.

```
from tkinter import *
from itertools import accumulate
from random import choices
from string import ascii_lowercase
```

I get the error that says 
    File "c:\Users\coope\Downloads\hw3.py", line 26, in 
    from random import choices
builtins.ImportError: cannot import name 'choices'

Comment: Upgrade your python version.

Answer (score 5):

Upgrade your python version. The `random.choices()` function was introduced in Python 3.6.

Quoting from the Library Documentation

> **random.choices**(population, weights=None, *, cum_weights=None, k=1)
>
> Return a k sized list of elements chosen from the population with replacement. If the population is empty, raises IndexError.

Compared to `random.choice`, the function `random.choices` returns not a single element but a k-sized list.

Answer (score 2):

`choices` is available only on `python3` and not in `python2`. So if you want to use `choices`, make sure you run your code in Python 3.x.

Here's a way to check if `choices` is present in python (2 or 3):

```
>>> import random
>>> dir(random)
```

**Edit:** As pointed out by Dmitri, it is only available in python3.6!